# CSS avoid overriding

Tags: css, dom

I want to override a css rule only if that rule is not already defined on that element. Specifically  - I want to give every element (using the `*` selector) a `position` of `relative` but not override any existing position.  So for example, if the element has an `absolute` position, then I want to leave it absolute.  If it has `fixed`, then leave it `fixed`.  Otherwise, make it `relative`.

I want to do this using css only.

Edit:  The use case is for a bookmarklet that is intended for css debugging, and I don't want to override anything existing.

FYI -> Here is the [bookmarklet](https://gist.github.com/dlgombert/99f881dcf8e81df133093c4fea6e1a2f) I'm working with.  Click it once to visualize, again to turn off the visualization.  It's pretty good for seeing how things lineup.

Comment: The `* { ... }` has a very very low priority. So you can do this without problem. Any other declaration will overrule this selector. A tag, class, id, or whatever has a higher priority and will overrule the `*`. Start with the `*` in your stylesheet and that's all

Comment: Make it the first rule, before all others. Any rules that follow will override it.

Comment: Just put your `* { ... }` at the beginning of the CSS file. Then any style definitions that follow will override your `* { ... }`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this. I can't think of a use case for adding it to everything.

Comment: In new design practice by using the flex model, the position:relative will not be nessecary. Only in special cases, for example with the position:absolute, it will be used on the parent of this element.

Comment: @bron - thanks.  Your first comment is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Paulie_D - just because you haven't thought of a use case for something doesn't mean that a use case doesn't exist.